# Python can't execute program even if I'm using absolute paths

Tags: python, ssh, absolute-path, subprocess

I'm running the command `/usr/bin/ssh 192.168.0.109` using Python's `subprocess` module. However, I'm getting a "File Not Found" error even though I'm using absolute paths.

```
OSError: Cannot run program "/usr/bin/ssh 192.168.0.109" (in directory "/home/max/repo/vssh/vssh"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I'm working in my home directory, but this should matter seeing as I'm giving the full path right?

Here's where the error occurs:

```
current_session = Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh " + x.address], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

<sup>(oh and `/usr/bin/ssh` does exist)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass in a list of strings to `Popen`, not a shell command line.

```
current_session = Popen(["/usr/bin/ssh", x.address], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

That should work better.